# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 85: 'translate', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to regis

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

Having issues with celery using django cookiecutter.  I am getting

django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 85: 'translate', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

[celery_app.py in config folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoFnk.png)

[locale folder[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P94LX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPotZ.png)

[Also getting this error while running docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1J7b.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

if you needany help you must add code so we can edit it.
this error It appears when you do not close the condition `if`

```
{%if condition%}
you html code
{%endif%}
```

you must read this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#if)